# Random Code at the top of every page

Tags: ee2

We just updated to the latest version of **Expression Engine 2 (2.11.6)**, but now it looks like there's some kind of code being injected at the very top of our page, right after the "body" tag:

> {!-- ra:00000000397d91950000000074865fe6 --}

It doesn't seem to be coming from any of our templates. Any idea why EE generates this random code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i've had the same thing today. in my case it was related to a php script in the templates that was trying to get images from flickr over the old api. However i have seen people mentioning it can also be caching related. So first thing would be to clear all caches

Comment: Modified some of the PHP of our website, and it worked! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue, when moving an old EE 2.9.3 site to a Dev server and applying a test domain name.
There were some PHP Includes in the templates, which referenced the live site's server path. When I changed these... all fixed.

For example:
include("/home/sites/domainname.co.uk/public_html/swift/swift_required.php");
...changed to...
include("/home/domain/public_html/swift/swift_required.php");